# What is the word for making a set of conflicting rules/policies make sense and all agree with one another?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a word for the act of taking a set of conflicting rules/policies and making it so that they no longer contradict one another and instead all agree. However, I can't think of it! Other words like streamline, clarify, restructure, etc. all don't include the connotation that previously the rules were contradictory, and now they are not. "Make consistent" is close, but I feel like there is a single word equivalent which is often used in e.g. business or government contexts. Any assistance figuring out what this word is would be very appreciated - I'd really like a single word/verb if possible.

An example of a sentence: "The new regulator [MAGIC WORD] the confusing mess of archaic policies so that there were no contradictions, and the requirements were now clear."

Comment: Try *reconcile*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the right word for your sentence is [conciliate](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/conciliate), which means

> To make or attempt to make compatible

This is very similar in meaning to [reconcile](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/reconcile) which means

> - To make compatible, harmonious, or consistent
>
> or
>
> - To make (two apparently conflicting things) compatible or consistent with each other

So your sentence would be

> The new regulator *conciliated* the confusing mess of archaic policies so that there were no contradictions, and the requirements were now clear.

You could also use *reconcile* here, and it would have the same meaning.

Comment: Thank you! Reconcile(/harmonize, which I found from the synonyms list) is what I was looking for!